# MSDN: How can I see what inherits/implements a class/interface?

Tags: inheritance, implementation, msdn

One thing I really, really miss from Javadoc is the ability to see which classes inherit the class you're looking at. So if you are looking at an abstract class (such as List) then you would be able to see all classes that inherit/implement the class/interface you're looking at. Is this available in the MSDN and I'm just missing it or is this really a missing feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such information is provided for *some* types (e.g. for [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)), unfortunately for very few. Can't say why it is so.

I'd recommend to use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to get such information. It's fast and easy.

Answer (score 1):

A better tool to use is [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm)

Comment: Note reflector finds child classes dynamically only for the set of assemblies it has open.